# Access users from Azure active Directory having persmison type as delegated

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to the Azure. I had a requirement retrieve the the users from Azure active directory. I am having Delegated Type, and user.Read and users.Readall.

I am able to get the bearer code but I am getting permission denied when it goes to retrieve the users.
I need to write a console application in c#, below is the code I tried .

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID)
               .WithClientSecret(Secret)
               .WithRedirectUri(URL)
               .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token")
               .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var token = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

 - GraphServiceClient graphClient1 = new
   GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", new
   DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
               {
                   requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.AccessToken);
               }));
   
               var users = graphClient1.Users.Request().Top(99).GetAsync();
               var organization = graphClient1.Organization.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

I am getting below

```
system.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
for the LIne **var organization = graphClient1.Organization.Request().GetAsync().Result;**
Need help on this
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delegated permissions only work when a user is involved in the authentication, which they aren't here. Any reason you can't use application permissions instead of delegated?

Comment: It told to me Only delegated permission will be given to the developer.So I need to get the output with Delegated permissions

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using delegated permissions it requires users to login to use these permisssions.So, `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is not the correct scope and it should be with delegated permission, For example `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`.

Also, you need to use await before the graph request,

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Top(99).GetAsync();
```

Since you are new to Ms Graph please go through a simple console app [code sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample) with helps you to implement easily.

Comment: Thanks Hari, I added await but still I am getting permissions error

Comment: I modified https://graph.microsoft.com/user.Read.All. which I am having permissions as deleged.But I am getting below error                                                                                                           MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.User.Read.All is not valid.
Trace ID: a22f9a96-3e4e-42f2-b699-340278118f00
Correlation ID: ddd30283-c37d-40cb-861b-f61391fd75fb
Timestamp: 2020-09-10 11:35:29Z

Comment: Hi @user3771062,Based on  the error message, you are passing no scope query parameter or invalid query parameter.please try with the sample I have shared with the [steps](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample#step-2--configure-your-azure-ad-tenant) in app registration.I hope it will help in fixing the issue.